# renaming html file to have parent directory name

Tags: html, file-rename

I have a directory tree in which each folder contains (at this point) a single html file, all with the same name.
I would like to rename each file so that it has the name of its parent directory.

For example, change

```
A\B\file1.html
A\C\file1.html
A\C\D\file1.html
E\file1.html
```

to

```
A\B\B.html
A\C\C.html
A\C\D\D.html
E\E.html
```

I did see another similar post on a similar problem for mp3 files, but was unable to adapt it.

I am pretty much a novice at this - been trying to find a way using Notepad++ and the Windows Command Prompt window, but no real idea so far.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to do this via code or do you just need an utility?

For bulk renaming of files I've been having a lot of luck using Bulk Rename Utility.
http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Comment: I downloaded and tried the utility. It takes a little bit of practice to understand all the options, but I think I can get it to do what I need. Brilliant!

Thanks.